# ImportError: No module named 'gnuradio'

Tags: python, eclipse, gnuradio

As a beginner I'm trying Coding in Python GNU Radio Applications. When I set the following code in the editor (Eclipse)

```
from gnuradio import gr
from gnuradio import audio, analog

class my_top_block(gr.top_block):
    def __init__(self):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self)

        sample_rate = 32000
        ampl = 0.1

        src0 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_SIN_WAVE, 350, ampl)
        src1 = analog.sig_source_f(sample_rate, analog.GR_SIN_WAVE, 440, ampl)
        dst = audio.sink(sample_rate, "")
        self.connect(src0, (dst, 0))
        self.connect(src1, (dst, 1))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        my_top_block().run()
    except [[KeyboardInterrupt]]:
        pass
```

It show the following error:

```
   **from gnuradio import gr

ImportError: No module named 'gnuradio':**
```

Any help will be really appreciated ?

Comment: format your code, it will be more readable

Comment: have you installed the package?

Comment: You mean gnuradio package ?

Comment: My setting : Windows 7, Eclipse, Pydev. I just use the import statement.

Comment: @Abs, yes the gnuradio package

Comment: @Padraic: No I just use the import statement. I could not find the package to install I tried this first.

Comment: @Abs, do you have https://gnuradio.org/redmine/versions/42 installed?

Comment: You might want to read this also https://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/WindowsInstall

Comment: @Padraic: No I should do ? I have gnuradio with gnuardio-companion install in ubuntu(Lab). I did not install it in windows. I though there is maybe a library or module/plugging we can just add it in Eclipse and get it working in windows !

Comment: @Abs, but you say you are using windows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77353/discussion-between-abs-and-padraic-cunningham).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing gnuradio module will solve the problem as suggested by @Padraic. I moved back to my lab in Ubuntu where I have gnuradio staff installed. Installed Eclipse on Ubuntu using gnuradio module and no error seen.